# How to generate listview as shown in Paint Image using Xamarin Forms, Example display shopping Items

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

[Please Check the Image for DisplayFormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dIL7.png)

I tried using AiForms but failed to trigger Image Tap event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display 2 entries in a row, you can create a `Grid` with 2 columns for each cell in the listview like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell Height="100">
                <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.1, 0.8, 0.5"/>
                        <Button BorderWidth="0" Clicked="ButtonClicked"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.1, 0.8, 0.5"/>
                        ...
                    </AbsoluteLayout>
                    <AbsoluteLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                        ...
                    </AbsoluteLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then For the image click event, you can overlay a transparent button on top of the image at the same location in the absolute layout (as shown in the code above).  You can set the `AutomationId` of the transparent button in C# if you want to distinguish the buttons from one another.

Comment: I want it to be auto generated as in the list view will have data binding.